# Excel file is not opening while export data in excel, but working fine in localhost

Tags: cakephp, export-to-excel

I face some problem in excel file. I am exporting excel file with data. This code is **working fine in localhost**. But in **live server**, the **excel file is not opening** and display message as

> Excel cannot open the file "users_download_.xlsx" because the file format or
> file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
> corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

My controller code is:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Controller\Admin\AppController;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\Utility\Hash;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use Cake\Http\CallbackStream;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    }

    public function exportUsers()
    {
        // Create a new spreadsheet
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        // Add value in a sheet inside of that spreadsheet. 
        // // (It's possible to have multiple sheets in a single spreadsheet)
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        // styles:
        $from = "A1";
        $to = "J1";
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("B")->setWidth(30);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("C")->setWidth(30);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("D")->setWidth(20);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("E")->setWidth(15);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("F")->setWidth(20);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("G")->setWidth(30);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("H")->setWidth(15);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("I")->setWidth(15);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("J")->setWidth(15);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("$from:$to")->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("$from:$to")->getFont()->setSize(14);
        $spreadsheet
            ->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A1:J1')
            ->getFill()
            ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
            ->getStartColor()
            ->setARGB('ff6a98fc');
        // styles end

        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Sr.No.');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Name');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Email');
        $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Mobile');
        $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'Total steps');
        $sheet->setCellValue('F1', 'Age group');
        $sheet->setCellValue('G1', 'Centre');
        $sheet->setCellValue('H1', 'State');
        $sheet->setCellValue('I1', 'Country');
        $sheet->setCellValue('J1', 'Gender');

        $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $users_list = $connection->execute(
            "SELECT
                fname,
                lname,
                email,
                agegroup_id,
                agegroups.NAME AS age_group_name,
                center,
                centremaster.centre AS centre_name,
                states.name AS state_name,
                countries.name AS country,
                gender,
                parent_email,
                mobile,
                user_name,
                parent_mobile,
                (SELECT SUM(steps) FROM steps WHERE steps.users_id=users.id) AS total_steps
            FROM
                `users`
                LEFT JOIN agegroups ON agegroups.id = users.agegroup_id
                LEFT JOIN centremaster ON centremaster.`id` = users.centreid
                LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.`id` = users.country_id
                LEFT JOIN states ON states.`id` = users.stateid
                "
        )->fetchAll('assoc');

        // $centres_list = [];
        foreach ($users_list as $key => $user) {
            $keyCell = $key + 2;
            if ($user['agegroup_id'] == 1) {
                // SSE CHILDREN
                $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $keyCell, $key + 1);
                $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $keyCell, $user['user_name']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $keyCell, $user['parent_email']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $keyCell, $user['parent_mobile']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $keyCell, $user['total_steps'] ?: 0);
                $sheet->setCellValue('F' . $keyCell, $user['age_group_name']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('G' . $keyCell, $user['centre_name']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('H' . $keyCell, $user['state_name']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $keyCell, $user['country']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('J' . $keyCell, $user['gender']);
            } else {
                $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $keyCell, $key + 1);
                $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $keyCell, $user['fname'] . " " . $user['lname']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $keyCell, $user['email']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $keyCell, $user['mobile']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $keyCell, $user['total_steps'] ?: 0);
                $sheet->setCellValue('F' . $keyCell, $user['age_group_name']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('G' . $keyCell, $user['centre_name']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('H' . $keyCell, $user['state_name']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $keyCell, $user['country']);
                $sheet->setCellValue('J' . $keyCell, $user['gender']);
            }
        }

        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        // ↓↓ Added new code from here in the eariler sample code
        // Save the file in a stream
        $stream = new CallbackStream(function () use ($writer) {
            $writer->save('php://output');
        });
        $filename = 'users_download_' . date('Y-m-d') . time();
        $response = $this->response;
        // Return the stream in a response
        return $response->withType('xlsx')
            ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment;filename=\"{$filename}.xlsx\"")
            ->withBody($stream);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Download the file, then open it with a text editor. Or check in your Cake error logs. It's almost certain that there's some error happening, output of which is corrupting the file.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I saw this msg : <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr65dd742c9f43f-trace').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr65dd742c9f43f-trace').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');"><b>Deprecated</b> (8192)</a>: Return type of MyCLabs\Enum\Enum::jsonSerialize() should either be compatible with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice [<b>ROOT/vendor/myclabs/php-enum/src/Enum.php</b>, line <b>246</b>]

Comment: Seems you have deprecation warnings enabled on your live server but not on localhost, or else you've updated something in one place but not the other.